# What is the middle-mouse-button alternative when one uses a laptop (only left and right button) with Blender 3d-modeling software installed?

Tags: 16.04, mouse, laptop, blender, button

I just downloaded the Blender 3d modeling software.  I am trying to use it on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04.  Since the middle mouse button is very important I am trying to find a way around that.  I did check the box "Emulate 3Button Mouse" at the "Input" theme under "User Preferences" and tried the alt+LMB (Left Mouse Button), action but I was not able to get the desired effect (scrolling).

Comment: Try clicking both LMB and RMB simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

When the [emulate 3 button mouse option](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/input.html#mouse) is enabled, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> will emulate the middle mouse button to orbit around the scene.

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> can be used to zoom in/out instead of the <kbd>[image: MMB] Wheel</kbd>.

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> can be used to pan the view.

Also <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> should emulate a <kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on a Mac with a one button mouse.